# XMLHttpRequest Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes in turn server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I am getting a  below error in chrome console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478/turn?username=username&key=key&transport=udp
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

while running a local webrtc sample server
  The node server example i am running is from https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server/

Below is the [image]screenshot

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to use `XMLHttpRequest` to make a request to a `turn:` URL?

Comment: I am just running the sample in the github  and the turn server is got expired so i just got a free trun server from twillo and runned it

Comment: What protocol do you use?

Comment: hi alex i used https protocol for the nodejs server to run

Comment: Can you add your front-end code? As others have mentioned, I am skeptical of the reason for making an XHR to a TURN server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a misunderstanding of what a TURN server is for, and are calling it as if it is a standard web server.

As some of the commenters mentioned, you're not supposed to make an HTTP request to a TURN server, which uses a different TURN protocol. Instead, you configure your WebRTC setup via the iceServer object, which is where you define a TURN server. The WebRTC implementation will use the TURN servers when required.

Here's a nice article about WebRTC signaling:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

And here's a couple other articles if you're interested in learning about the specific protocols WebRTC uses:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/stun-turn/faq

Comment: HI Michael thanks for your answer but i am not at all trying to make a http or https request i am simply trying to run the sample code also trun/stun server is used for signaling purpose and media transvasal. I have already created a local turn server and tried to integrated same error may be ill post the code here, Thanks again